# RegisterService and handler methods are not getting generate gRPC and go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I was trying to implement an example from internet for gRPC integration with go. 
https://dzone.com/articles/writing-a-microservice-in-golang-which-communicate

So in the generated file there are no RegisterServer methods not the handler for the methods inside services.

my repository-service.proto file

```
package service;

option go_package = "grpc_test/internal/gRPC/service";

import "grpc_test/internal/proto-files/domain/repository.proto";

//RepositoryService Definition
service RepositoryService {
    rpc add (domain.Repository) returns (AddRepositoryResponse);
}

message AddRepositoryResponse {
    domain.Repository addedRepository = 1;
    Error error = 2;
}
message Error {
    string code = 1;
    string message = 2;
}
```

the generated .pb.go file

```
// source: grpc_test/internal/proto-files/service/repository-service.proto

package service

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    domain "grpc_test/internal/gRPC/domain"
    math "math"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal
var _ = fmt.Errorf
var _ = math.Inf

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3 // please upgrade the proto package

type AddRepositoryResponse struct {
    AddedRepository      *domain.Repository `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=addedRepository,proto3" json:"addedRepository,omitempty"`
    Error                *Error             `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=error,proto3" json:"error,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}           `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte             `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32              `json:"-"`
}

func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) Reset()         { *m = AddRepositoryResponse{} }
func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*AddRepositoryResponse) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*AddRepositoryResponse) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_621a2418b03aa6f6, []int{0}
}

func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse.Size(m)
}
func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_AddRepositoryResponse proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) GetAddedRepository() *domain.Repository {
    if m != nil {
        return m.AddedRepository
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *AddRepositoryResponse) GetError() *Error {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Error
    }
    return nil
}

type Error struct {
    Code                 string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=code,proto3" json:"code,omitempty"`
    Message              string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=message,proto3" json:"message,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func (m *Error) Reset()         { *m = Error{} }
func (m *Error) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*Error) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*Error) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_621a2418b03aa6f6, []int{1}
}

func (m *Error) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Error.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *Error) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Error.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *Error) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_Error.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *Error) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Error.Size(m)
}
func (m *Error) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_Error.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_Error proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *Error) GetCode() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Code
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *Error) GetMessage() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Message
    }
    return ""
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterType((*AddRepositoryResponse)(nil), "service.AddRepositoryResponse")
    proto.RegisterType((*Error)(nil), "service.Error")
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterFile("grpc_test/internal/proto-files/service/repository-service.proto", fileDescriptor_621a2418b03aa6f6)
}

var fileDescriptor_621a2418b03aa6f6 = []byte{
    // 248 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xff, 0xe2, 0xb2, 0x4f, 0x2f, 0x2a, 0x48,
    0x8e, 0x2f, 0x49, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0xd1, 0xcf, 0xcc, 0x2b, 0x49, 0x2d, 0xca, 0x4b, 0xcc, 0xd1, 0x2f,
    0x28, 0xca, 0x2f, 0xc9, 0xd7, 0x4d, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0x49, 0x2d, 0xd6, 0x2f, 0x4e, 0x2d, 0x2a, 0xcb,
    0x4c, 0x4e, 0xd5, 0x2f, 0x4a, 0x2d, 0xc8, 0x2f, 0xce, 0x2c, 0xc9, 0x2f, 0xaa, 0xd4, 0x85, 0x0a,
    0xe9, 0x81, 0x95, 0x09, 0xb1, 0x43, 0xb9, 0x52, 0x66, 0x04, 0x4c, 0x4a, 0xc9, 0xcf, 0x4d, 0xcc,
    0xcc, 0x43, 0x32, 0x08, 0x62, 0x80, 0x52, 0x35, 0x97, 0xa8, 0x63, 0x4a, 0x4a, 0x10, 0x5c, 0x38,
    0x28, 0xb5, 0xb8, 0x20, 0x3f, 0xaf, 0x38, 0x55, 0xc8, 0x86, 0x8b, 0x3f, 0x31, 0x25, 0x25, 0x15,
    0x49, 0x4a, 0x82, 0x51, 0x81, 0x51, 0x83, 0xdb, 0x48, 0x48, 0x0f, 0x62, 0x96, 0x1e, 0x92, 0x26,
    0x74, 0xa5, 0x42, 0x2a, 0x5c, 0xac, 0xa9, 0x45, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x45, 0x12, 0x4c, 0x60, 0x3d, 0x7c,
    0x7a, 0x30, 0x67, 0xbb, 0x82, 0x44, 0x83, 0x20, 0x92, 0x4a, 0xa6, 0x5c, 0xac, 0x60, 0xbe, 0x90,
    0x10, 0x17, 0x4b, 0x72, 0x7e, 0x4a, 0x2a, 0xd8, 0x06, 0xce, 0x20, 0x30, 0x5b, 0x48, 0x82, 0x8b,
    0x3d, 0x37, 0xb5, 0xb8, 0x38, 0x31, 0x3d, 0x15, 0x6c, 0x08, 0x67, 0x10, 0x8c, 0x6b, 0xe4, 0xc7,
    0x25, 0x88, 0xb0, 0x2a, 0x18, 0x62, 0xb0, 0x90, 0x25, 0x17, 0x73, 0x62, 0x4a, 0x8a, 0x10, 0x16,
    0xd7, 0x49, 0xc9, 0xc1, 0x6d, 0xc7, 0xea, 0x55, 0x27, 0xc5, 0x28, 0x79, 0x2c, 0xa1, 0x97, 0x1e,
    0x14, 0xe0, 0x0c, 0x8b, 0x80, 0x24, 0x36, 0x70, 0x68, 0x19, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff,
    0x27, 0x43, 0x03, 0x2a, 0xb1, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

Ideally it should have "RegisterRepositoryServiceServer" method but it's not getting generated, seems like i have missed something during installation.

Command for generating stub is

`protoc -I $GOPATH/src --go_out=plugins=gRPC:$GOPATH/src $GOPATH/src/path to .proto file`

Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: can you upload the full source of your test somewhere?

Comment: Is `repository.proto` somewhere in your include path?

Comment: @colminator yes

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E5cQtDmbruqJdnfDnVyLwzkV8YOhYNFj?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the use of `gRPC` instead of `grpc` in the `protoc` command-line. Try with:

```sh
$ protoc -I$GOPATH/src --go_out=plugins=grpc:$GOPATH/src PATH_TO_PROTO_FILE
```

Comment: that worked, but i had gRPC command in server as well, but it wasn't getting imported thats why i used grpc, i know it may be irrelevent to the question but what is so much different b/w grpc and gRPC ?

Comment: @whishky not sure, maybe there are multiple paths in protoc/protoc-gen-go that consider the plugins value, where in some it's considered in a case-insensitive way, and not in others, but this is only a wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still facing a problem with this issue. Apparently, Plugins are no longer supported. You can use `--go-grpc_out=path_to_out` instead of `go_out=plugins=grpc:path_to_out`

Full example `protoc -I. --go-grpc_out=. path_to_proto_file` This will generate all the functions and methods

Comment: In my case the following worked: `protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. path_to_proto_file.proto`